# Can ciphertext output of AES or RSA encryption be limited to the ASCII-128 character table?

Tags: encryption, character-encoding, ascii, aes, rsa

I'm doing an R&D project focused on encrypting information into cipher-text and then printing it as a Code-128 barcode.

It is my understanding that since code-128 barcodes can only retain the ASCII table up to 128 characters. Therefore, I need to know if the cipher-text output of modern algorithms such as AES or RSA can be restricted to only the ASCII-128 table.

I am not doing any programming at this point, I am mainly trying to find precedence that this is can be done or has been done.  If anyone knows the answer to this question, and better yet could provide a reference to an example, I would be very grateful.

bonus question... if restricting the ciphertext to ascii-128 is possible, how much could it affect encryption strength?

Comment: Are the 0..0x20 bytes allowed? Is 0x7F allowed as well? It seems not "103 data symbols" if I have to believe Wikipedia on the matter.

Comment: This is close to format preserving encryption. Of course it is possible to create a ciphertext base 103, and it won't affect cipher strength. It may however be tricky to keep the overhead low enough to fit everything into the barcode. Althought he wiki page does not specify how much data can be encoded, I presume there will be a practical limit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [cryptography](http://cryptography.stackexchange.com) without involving programming.

Answer (score 0):

Encode resulting cipher-text, which is binary, with [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which is ASCII. Then you will be able to print base64-encoded cipher-text as 
barcode.

Since Base64 encoding decoding doesn't change content, but rather changes its presentation, it doesn't affect underlying cryptography strength.

If resulting data won't fit into 103 (255) characters of Code 128, consider using [QR Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) instead.